# Parsing and creating JSON packets

Tags: java, json, gson

For several of my pet projects, I have had to interpret and/or send JSON WebSocket or HTTP responses in Java. I did some research and picked the library GSON to use. In each project, I have implemented a custom deserializer in order to correctly interpret different packet types.

For example:

> ```
> {"type": "set-name", "data":{"name":"daniel"}}
> {"type": "set-timeperiod", "data":{"start":"2017-03-16", "end":"2017-03-17"}}
> ```

In this case I would use two classes, `SetName` and `SetTimePeriod`:

> ```
> public class SetName implements Data {
>     private String name;
>
>     @Override
>     public void handle(Foo foo) throws InvalidPacketException {
>         if(name == null) throw new InvalidPacketException();
>         foo.doThingWithName(name);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public String getType() { return "set-name"; }
> }
> ```

`Foo` represents any arbitrary resources, the packet might need to perform its function. The data interface is fairly straightforward:

```
public interface Data {
    void handle(Foo foo);
    String getType();
}
```

The `Data` objects are wrapped in a Packet representing the whole thing:

```
public void Packet {
    private String type;
    private Data data;

    public Packet(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
        type = data.getType();
    }

    public void handle(Foo foo) throws InvalidPacketException { data.handle(foo); }

    public Packet initData(Data data) {
        if(this.data != null) throw new IllegalStateException("Data already initialised.");
        this.data = data;
        return this;
    }
}
```

And finally, the packet would be converted from raw JSON to an instance of `Packet` using a custom Deserializer.

```
public class PacketDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Packet> {

    @Override
    public Packet deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
        throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        // Remove data object, GSON won't know what to turn it into.
        JsonObject dataObject = jsonObject.remove("data").getAsJsonObject();
        // Determine what type of data object we need.
        Class dataClass = typeToClass(jsonObject.get("type").getAsString());
        // Construct and return a Packet of the correct type.
        Data data = context.deserialize(dataObject, dataClass);
        return new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject, Packet.class).initData(data);
    }

    private Class<? extends Data> typeToClass(String type) throws JsonParseException {
        switch(type) {
            case("set-name"): return SetName.class;
            case("set-timeperiod"): return SetTimePeriod.class;
            default: throw new JsonParseException("Type " + type + " is invalid.");
        }
    }
}
```

This means GSON will now deserialize the object into a `Packet` and then call the `handle()` to do whatever needs to be done with that packet:

```
Packet packet = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(Packet.class, new PacketDeserializer())
    .create()
    .fromJson(message, Packet.class);
packet.handle(foo);
```

In addition, a `Packet` instance can be converted to JSON without the need for any custom serializer. Once this structure is built, it is very easy to add new packet types or to send/parse packets.

This seems like an elegant solution to me, but I have some concerns:

- Is it actually efficient? Would it be much faster to parse the JSON directly?
- I can end up with a *lot* of subclasses of `Data` which makes me feel like there could be a better way of doing it
- If this is a good solution, would it be a good thing to use wherever I'm parsing JSON with some object with varying contents like `data`?

I came up with this solution years ago, when I was fairly new to programming and haven't changed it much at all, so I feel like I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't Packet initialize `String type`?

Comment: Gson does not require a constructor. However, I do usually provide a constructor for the purposes of serializing packets. I will add one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a few comments:

- [Data transfer objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object), that Gson works with, fields may be `final` and hold `null`s by default (with some other remarks to primitive types that require a kind of cheating at `javac`).
- These Data Transfer Objects may also have private constructors, because Gson does not need any. This and the previous items are just less error-prone (you can neither instantiate such an incoming DTO manually nor change its state).
- You don't need `Packet.initData`.
- `SetName` and `SetTimePeriod` do similar things, and can be refactored to have a common super class that implements the [template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).
- I have a feeling that `messsage` is a string. Prefer stream-oriented classes like `InputStream`, `Reader` and `JsonReader` in order to avoid unnecessary buffering (not a very suitable for your case, because you still have `JsonElement` (that's a buffer per se) in your deserializer) -- this will work just fine for bigger objects.
- Also consider extracting `Gson` instance simply to `static` `final` fields. `Gson` is immutable and thread-safe, therefore it can be easily shared across multiple-threads.
- `PacketDeserializer` holds no state and be made a singleton without any negative impacts. Consider hiding constructors as much as possible too.
- Having that in mind, consider returning the most super-type as you can: `public static JsonDeserializer<Packet> get() { ... }`. This would allow you not bother for concrete types used at call-site.
- Modifying arguments is a bad practice making a lot of surprises to anyone not expecting such a behavior: `jsonObject.remove("data")` (additionally this is just unnecessary and makes no effect for you).
- You should not create `Gson` instances in serializers and deserializers and do all such stuff via contexts only. First of all, `Gson` instances are relatively expensive to instantiate. Additionally, such a `Gson` object may have totally different configuration, other that the "global" `Gson` instance has. However, I suspect that you made this choice in order to avoid infinite recursion.
- `PacketDeserializer.typeToClass` can be static.
- `switch`es with `(` and `)` `case`s look unusual.
- By the way, string `switch`es are totally fine for such kind of mapping.
- `Packet` does not need `type`.

As the result:

```java
final class InvalidPacketException
        extends IOException {
}
```

```java
interface Data {

    void handle(Foo foo)
            throws InvalidPacketException;

    String getType();

}
```

```java
abstract class AbstractData
        implements Data {

    private transient String type;

    protected AbstractData(final String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    protected abstract boolean isValid();

    protected abstract void doHandle(Foo foo);

    @Override
    public final void handle(final Foo foo)
            throws InvalidPacketException {
        if ( !isValid() ) {
            throw new InvalidPacketException();
        }
        doHandle(foo);
    }

    @Override
    public final String getType() {
        return type;
    }

}
```

```java
final class SetName
        extends AbstractData {

    private final String name = null;

    private SetName() {
        super("set-name");
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isValid() {
        return name != null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doHandle(final Foo foo) {
        foo.doThingWithName(name);
    }

}
```

```java
final class SetTimePeriod
        extends AbstractData {

    private final Date start = null;
    private final Date end = null;

    private SetTimePeriod() {
        super("set-timeperiod");
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isValid() {
        return start != null && end != null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doHandle(final Foo foo) {
        foo.doThingWithStartAndEnd(start, end);
    }

}
```

```java
final class Packet {

    private final Data data;

    private Packet(final Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    static Packet of(final Data data) {
        return new Packet(data);
    }

    void handle(final Foo foo)
            throws InvalidPacketException {
        data.handle(foo);
    }

}
```

```java
final class PacketDeserializer
        implements JsonDeserializer<Packet> {

    private static final JsonDeserializer<Packet> instance = new PacketDeserializer();

    private PacketDeserializer() {
    }

    static JsonDeserializer<Packet> get() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public Packet deserialize(final JsonElement jsonElement, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        final JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        final JsonElement dataJsonElement = jsonObject.get("data");
        final Type dataType = resolveType(jsonObject.get("type").getAsString());
        final Data data = context.deserialize(dataJsonElement, dataType);
        return Packet.of(data);
    }

    private static Type resolveType(final String type)
            throws JsonParseException {
        switch ( type ) {
        case "set-name":
            return SetName.class;
        case "set-timeperiod":
            return SetTimePeriod.class;
        default:
            throw new JsonParseException("Type " + type + " is invalid.");
        }
    }

}
```

```java
final class Foo {

    void doThingWithName(final String name) {
        System.out.println("NAME: " + name);
    }

    void doThingWithStartAndEnd(final Date start, final Date end) {
        System.out.println("START: " + start + "; END:" + end);
    }

}
```

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Packet.class, PacketDeserializer.get())
        .create();

public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException {
    final Foo foo = new Foo();
    for ( final String name : ImmutableList.of("name.json", "timeperiod.json") ) {
        // I'm just reading these as JsonReader-ed resources from the package the Q189789 class is nested at
        try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = Resources.getPackageResourceJsonReader(Q189789.class, name) ) {
            final Packet packet = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Packet.class);
            packet.handle(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
NAME: daniel
START: Thu Mar 16 00:00:00 EET 2017; END:Fri Mar 17 00:00:00 EET 2017
```

Gson also has a very convenient [type adapter](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java) for your case. Note that this is an example and the type adapter is not bundled with Gson. You might want just to include it into your codebase.

Comment: Thank you very much for this review, it teaches me a lot! Just wanted to explain points 3, 9 and 14: These apparently unnecessary things are used for when I need an ID, timestamp or other meta info in the Packet class, and not in the Data class. However, I should have said this in the question!

Answer (score 3):

A quick braindump:

- `PacketDeserializer#deserialize`  is overcommented. Most comments restate what the code says. Try commenting as little as possible, but as much as necessary.
- `PacketDeserializer` could benefit from not hardcoding the mapping between the type strings and classes. Consider passing a `Map<String, Class<? extends Data>>` as constructor parameter and replacing `typeToClass` with a `map.get`
- Lastly you should also avoid rawtypes. `Class` without generics specification is a rawtype.

Continuing that thought, you really want a different name than `Foo` for the `"PacketHandler"` you pass in to `Packet#handle`. You should consider going so far as to extract the responsibility of handling the package into a separate class. A Packet should not know how to handle itself. It's originally just a data-holder, nothing intelligent :)